# Spring Boot Kafka Streams - unknown binder configuration error

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am trying to using spring cloud Kafka Streams(KStreams) as a consumer to connect to a kafka topic and do some business logic and the goal is to push it to another kafka cluster topic.
Here the consumer connection to kafka cluster itself is failing with the with the below error..

My Spring application.yml file

```
spring:
  application:
    name: consumer-test-service
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: vehicleFeedConsumer
      bindings:
        vehicleFeedConsumer-in-0:
          destination: vehicle-feed-kafka-topic-1
          binder: vehConKstream

        # Here we will have a producer binding to push the processed data to diff cluster/topic
      binders:
        vehConKstream:
          type: kstream
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    streams:
                      binder:
                        brokers: eastus2.***********.com:9093 # kafka cluster url
                        applicationId: vehicle-binder-kafka-streams
                        jaas:
                          loginModule: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
                          options:
                            username: user123
                            password: password123
                        configuration:
                          commit.interval.ms: 100
                          security.protocol: SASL_SSL
                          sasl.mechanishm: PLAIN
                          default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                          default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                          auto.offset.reset: earliest
logging:
  pattern:
    file: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%"
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"
  level:
    org:
      springframework: DEBUG
    com:
      azure: DEBUG
    spring: DEBUG
```

the connection is failing with the below error.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown binder configuration: kstream
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:330)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinderConventional(DefaultBinderFactory.java:214)
```

all the configuration seems to be valid and not sure of the failure cause.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that you've added `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams` dependency to your application

Comment: Hello Nikolai. I have these as part of my pom.. still getting no binder exception.
                        <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
  </dependency>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: Can you share your topology code?
It will be clearer if we saw what is the expected binding.